# Bootstrap 3 multiselect plugin as form element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add [multiselect plugin](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) to my form.
I've managed to get everything working just fine (http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/t2qaP/), but I would like to get that select to be 100% width.
I can add css by hand:

```
 .btn-group, .btn-group .multiselect {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

but maybe there is better way of doing this with bootstrap?

here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/t2qaP/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Again hello ;)
See

**UPDATED**

http://jsfiddle.net/t2qaP/13/

```
select.multiselect,
select.multiselect + div.btn-group,
select.multiselect + div.btn-group button.multiselect,
select.multiselect + div.btn-group.open .multiselect-container{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

**UPDATED 2**
You need to add `buttonClass` to multiselect options. But why do it? Looks so good.
http://jsfiddle.net/t2qaP/14/

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonClass: 'form-control'
});
```

[image]

Comment: I've checked Your answer, it works better as it also affects select list. BTW how can I get that button to look as input - blue focus etc?

Comment: I wanted to get look that all elements look the same. Thank You :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was expecting that the multiselect site would have provided in its examples or such.

Comment: Not render correctly think the links are broken as of 2019 :(

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use `buttonWidth` option if you do not wish to modify css. See below example.

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonWidth: '411px'// here you need to specify width value
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2qaP/11/)

Comment: I've added `buttonWidth: '100%'` and it worked fine :)

Comment: Can we modify the height of the button? I tried adding buttonHeight but it does not do anything..

Comment: @KevinCohen I think there is no such option called buttonHeight. You should be able to increase height of the button with simple css hack. Can you create a fiddle with code you tried? I can help with css hack then.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/t2qaP/12/

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker();
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonClass : "col-sm-12"
});
```

The multiselect plugin allow to manage this.