# Bootstrap 3 btn-group width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have another Bootstrap related problem.
I want to add radio and checkboxes to my form, I would like them also to take 100% width of form element.

I've added button group as this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subscribe</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="btn-group input-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />Yes</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" />Maybe</label>
            <label class="btn btn-danger">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" />No</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives me nice radio-like buttons:

[image]

But as You can see they have fixed width. Can this be fixed with bootstrap classes?
Again here is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/yy5HZ/5/

Comment: @Misiu just add the `.btn-group-justified` built in class to the `.btn-group`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the built in `.btn-group-justified` class: [Offical Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified)

> Make a group of buttons stretch at equal sizes to span the entire
>   width of its parent. Also works with button dropdowns within the
>   button group.

**Anchors:**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group"> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Left</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Middle</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Right</a> 
</div>
```

**Buttons:**

> To use justified button groups with `<button>` elements, **you must wrap**
>   **each button in a button group**. Most browsers don't properly apply our
>   CSS for justification to `<button>` elements, but since we support
>   button dropdowns, we can work around that.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ2f7/)

Comment: And that's the answer that I was searching for. I knew that bootstrap has this build in :) Thanks! BTW could You look at my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803189/bootstrap-3-multiselect-plugin-as-form-element

Comment: Mentioned in the documentation, but bears repeating here: **each button inside a _btn-group-justified_ must be individually wrapped in a second _btn-group_**.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the bootstrap col-n classes so if you have 2 buttons you use `col-xs-6` on them. The problem is when you have 5 buttons for example. There is no class for that in the bootstrap grid system. So I woul use one of the following:

To differenciate between groups with different number of buttons use additional custom classes:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS5Zc/)**

CSS

```
.btn-group {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-group-2 label.btn  {
    width: 50%;
}
.btn-group-3 label.btn  {
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-3 input-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />Yes</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" />Maybe</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" />No</label>
</div>
```

If you want to avoid these css classes you can only use jQuery:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MC6M5/)

```
$('.btn-group').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).find('.btn').css(
        'width', 100 / $(item).find('.btn').length + '%'
    )
});
```

Comment: what about 2 buttons? i must create another class?

Comment: @Misiu So now you have two ways of doing it. One of them should be suitable for you. :)

Comment: Yes :) They both are fine :) Thanks for both solution, I was trying @Valerie solution but without any luck. I'll probably stay with css only solution. Sadly this isn't build into bootstrap by default. Thanks again!

Comment: Why not just use the `.btn-group-justified` built in class?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
.btn-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.btn-group > button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For boostrap 4 the docs say you can do this:

Removed `.btn-group-justified`. As a replacement you can use `<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group"></div>` as a wrapper around elements with `.w-100`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a class of your own and give them a 33% width (for the 3 buttons) or 50% width (for the 2 buttons).

Comment: I know about that, but this way I must create specific classes if I have 4, 5, 6 buttons. I want to avoid that

Comment: What about giving them the col-classes from bootstrap?  [Bootstrap grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: @Valerie And what do you do with let's say 5 buttons?

Comment: Hm, you tricked me :D I know I did something like that in a replica-project, I'll put my code in the edit of my post

Comment: Hm, I saw that was with a wrapper and stuff, also with a lot of classes added, so probably not what you're looking for. Maybe you could do it with jquery? If you know the number of buttons, you could split your width through the number of buttons, make it a percentage and add it as width to de class of your button(s)

Answer (score 0):

If @Schmalzy's solution doesn't work then you might be using Bootstrap v3.0.0, for which add the following styles in addition to the html markup in @Schmalzy's solution.

```
.btn-group-justified > .btn-group .btn {
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-group-justified > .btn, .btn-group-justified > .btn-group {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
}
```