# Bootstrap - Button toolbar width 100% - using btn-group's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problems with getting the bootstrap toolbar to fill 100% from left to right when i use **btn-group**'s

I have tried use: **btn-group-justified**

[Example without btn-group-justified](http://satori.ramgaard.net/test/1.html)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example with btn-group-justified](http://satori.ramgaard.net/test/2.html)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar btn-group-justified" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also the function: width="100%" does not work. any suggestions? or alternatives?

Thanky you.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: the code has been added now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 btn-group width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804104/bootstrap-3-btn-group-width)

Comment: @Feeco no: the solution in that question was already attempted, and the issue here is with `btn-toolbar` not `btn-group`

Answer (score 2):

Use btn-block class and col-xx-yy class:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-default col-lg-4" type="button">Left 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default col-lg-4" type="button">Left 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default col-lg-4" type="button">Left 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution is to add an extra btn-group div into the hierarchy and use btn-group-justified on that, i.e.

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Left 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Left 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Left 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Middle 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Middle 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Middle 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Right 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Right 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Right 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```